# What should be used instead of Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit

One of our users has an Excel VBA project that references Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0.  The corresponding MSCOMCTL.OCX file is no longer in our image, and so of course the project won't run due to a missing reference.

Rather than installing  [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Common Controls](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019) on our Windows 7 64-bit systems with Office 2016 64-bit, is there something different that the user can reference in their project that is more modern and supported?

Side question: If we do install it, will it even be able to work, with 64-bit Excel calling a 32-bit OCX?
Answer: I tried on a 64-bit Office installation, and the answer is No.  You can install it, register it, and reference it, but you can't actually use any of the UI controls from it.  They simply don't appear in the list.

Comment: do you know what control it was they were using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't, I'm just a consultant here and did not work directly with the user.

Comment: its normally been the calendar control, some use DateTimePicker or write their own.  Writing your own isn't as difficult as it sounds, just takes a bit of time, setting out the buttons ect.

Comment: If you want to be able to have any kind of backwards-compatibility between Office and other software/components then the 32-bit version would be much easier to deal with.

Comment: Don't I know it.  However, the company has decided they want 64-bit for greater Excel capacity, so here we are.